# Poco::Data::MySQL 'Got packets out of order' error

Tags: c++, mysql, poco-libraries

I got an `ER_NET_PACKETS_OUT_OF_ORDER` error when running a multithreaded C++ app using `Poco::Data::MySQL` and `Poco::Data::SessionPool`. The error message looks like this:

```
MySQL: [MySQL]: [Comment]: mysql_stmt_prepare error [mysql_stmt_error]: Got packets out of order    [mysql_stmt_errno]: 1156    [mysql_stmt_sqlstate]: 08S01    [statemnt]: ...
```

The app is making queries from multiple threads every 100ms. The connections are provided by a common `SessionPool`.

Answer (score 0):

I got around this problem by adding `reset=true` to the connection string. However, as stated in the [official docs](https://docs.pocoproject.org/current/Poco.Data.MySQL.SessionImpl.html#1698), adding this option may result in problems with encoding.